# React: Copy values from one input field to another when checking checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a form in which I have two address field groups (think of it as shipping and billing address).
I want to offer the user the opportunity to copy values from one group into another when checking a checkbox "Billing address is the same as shipping address".

My code looks as follows:

```js
class PetitionForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Form 
                onValidSubmit={this._handleValidSubmit.bind(this)}
                onInvalidSubmit={this._handleInvalidSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <div className="panel panel-default">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        <h2 className="panel-title">Shipping Address</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <ValidatedInput name="streetShip" type="text" label="Street" validate="required" errorHelp="Needs to be completed" groupClassName="col-sm-12"/>
                        <ValidatedInput name="zipShip" type="number" label="ZIP Code" validate="required" errorHelp="Needs to be completed" groupClassName="col-xs-4"/>
                        <ValidatedInput name="cityShip" type="text" label="City" validate="required" errorHelp="Needs to be completed" groupClassName="col-xs-8"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="panel panel-default">
                    <div className="panel-heading">
                        <h2 className="panel-title">Billing Address</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <Input type="checkbox" ref="checkbox" name="sameCheck" label="Shipping address is billing address" onChange={this._copyAddress} />
                        <ValidatedInput name="streetBill" type="text" label="Street" validate="required" errorHelp="Needs to be completed" groupClassName="col-sm-12" />
                        <ValidatedInput name="zipBill" type="number" label="ZIP Code" validate="required" errorHelp="Needs to be completed" groupClassName="col-xs-4"/>
                        <ValidatedInput name="cityBill" type="text" label="Ciudad" validate="required" errorHelp="Needs to be completed" groupClassName="col-xs-8"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ButtonInput type="submit" groupClassName="col-sm-12" />
            </Form>
        );
    }

    _copyAddress() {
        this.refs.checkbox.getValue();
    }

    _handleValidSubmit(values) {
      // handle submit
    }

    _handleInvalidSubmit(errors, values) {
      // handle invalids
    }
}
```

The `onChange={this._copyAddress}` is my desperate attempt to capture when the checkbox is being checked. `copyAddress` is being triggered, but `this.refs.checkbox` is undefined.

Even then if that worked, how would I get the values from the upper form group?

Thanks for your help!

- Hg

Comment: why don't you use the `e.target` from `_copyAddress(e)`? (And your spelling is off :/

Comment: Thanks, renamed the functions when creating the snippet, so luckily, that wasn't the issue.
```e.target.checked``` does the trick, but I found out what caused ```this.refs.checkbox is undefined```—it should be ```onChange={this._copyAddress}.bind(this)```

Now I'm still stuck at how to copy over the values. :-(

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html Use the lifecycles. Then use state to give the values to the form.

Comment: States solved it—thanks! See below for the answer, I appreciate any feedback on the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of my initial problems could be solved by binding `this` to the `onChange` call:

`onChange={this._copyAddress.bind(this)}`

That way, I was able to access `this.refs.checkbox`.

For copying the values, I first had to bind the values to the component state, turning them into controlled components (see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

That meant setting the state as follows (I'm using ES6 classes):

```
class PetitionForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            values: {
                firstName: "",
                lastName: "",
                email: "",
                streetShip: "",
                zipShip: "",
                cityShip: "",
                streetBill: "",
                zipBill: "",
                cityBill: ""
            }
        };
    }
...
}
```

For each of the Inputs, we have to now add the value-property: `value={this.state.values.firstName}`

Now, if we left it at that, the user can't make any changes to the form, hence we have to wire up the `onChange` property with a `handleChange` function. Because I did not want to write 9 different handlers for the 9 fields, this was my shortcut:

```
handleChange(e) {
    var key = e.target.name;
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = e.target.value;
    var updatedValues = Object.assign({}, this.state.values, obj);
    this.setState({values: updatedValues});
}
```

The `target.name` is equivalent to the key we used to set up the state-values. `e.target.value` captures the user input. `Object.assign` is used to avoid messing directly with the state (which should be treated as immutable).
Great guidance on the problem when manipulating the state is provided [here](https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c#.ppjp56ox3)

Copying the contents is then pretty straightforward:

```
_copyAddress(e) {
    if(this.refs.copyAddress.getChecked()) {
        var obj = {
                streetBill: this.state.values.streetShip,
                zipBill: this.state.values.zipShip,
                cityBill: this.state.values.cityShip
        }
        var updatedValues = Object.assign({}, this.state.values, obj);
        this.setState({values: updatedValues});
    }
}
```

The checkbox triggering the copy and on exemplary input field now look like this:

```
<Input type="checkbox" name="copyAddress" ref="copyAddress" label="Same as shipping" onChange={this._copyAddress.bind(this)} />
<ValidatedInput name="streetBills" value={this.state.values.streetBills} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} type="text" label="Street" ... />
```

Not sure how "reactly" this is—let me know if you have feedback!

Comment: What's the reason for using an underscore for the _copyAddress but not for the handleChange method?